# Two users, same username, same avatar

Tags: discussion

What is the procedure one should follow if two accounts by (what seems to be) the same person are discovered?

I know they should be merged (if confirmed) but I don't see a flag option on the user account screen.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just flag one of their posts for moderator attention and explain the situation.

Comment: And in case of no posts you can post the details here.